# Probability for effect of intervention

Tags: probability

Say that 40 % of patients with disease X recover without treatment. With a specific treatment 80% of the patients recover. 
You are going to give the treatment to a randomly chosen  patient with this disease. What is the chance for the treatment  to make him recover?